# Confusing Lisp syntax with (operator-integer-operator) format

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp and I had a question about this LISP syntax:

```
(defparameter *binary-operators*
  '((+ 1 +) (- 1 -) (* 2 *)
    (x 2 *) (/ 2 %) (^ 3 expt)))
```

From what I understand, defparameter allows the binary operators variable to be reassigned but I am confused as to how the (+ 1 +), (- 1 -) ... are evaluated. I know in LISP that (+ 4 6) would result in (4 + 6) = 10 but the same logic would result in (1 + +) which does not make sense. What does the above syntax represent?

Comment: http://www.lispology.com/show?JIH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Common Lisp,

```
(defparameter name initial-value)
```

(see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm#defparameter)) introduces a new special (global) variable `name` with a new value, given by evaluating `initial-value`.

So, in the example above, the special variable `*binary-operators*` is assigned a list of triples, each of them constitued by a symbol, a number, and another symbol. In other words, it assigns some data to a variable, and not, as you were thinking, redefines the syntax of the language.

Guessing from the values present in the list, this seems a variable that is assigned a list of arithmetic operators, each of them with the priority, and with the equivalent Common Lisp operator/function. Maybe this is a line of some program that maps arithmetic expressions in lisp s-expressions, or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

**Lisp: lists and symbols are used in data and in code**

This is one of the applications where code is data. In Lisp symbols and lists are data. But they are also used to write programs: the symbols then are used for *variable names*, *function names* and much more. Lists are used to write expressions in the Lisp language - these are called *forms*.

In a Lisp program

```
(+ 1 2)
```

is a function call of the function named `+` with two values.

```
'(+ 1 2)
```

or

```
(quote (+ 1 2))
```

then is data -> the list of the symbol `+` and the numbers `1` and `2`.

**Example: infix to prefix conversion**

The form you used defines a mapping from a symbol denoting a mathematical function to the weight and the actual Lisp function it represents for the conversion.

See [Lispology: Infix to prefix](http://lispology.com/show?JIH)

```
(defparameter *binary-operators*
  ;  operator  weight  Lisp function
  '((+         1       +)
    (-         1       -)
    (*         2       *)
    (x         2       *)
    (/         2       %)
    (^         3       expt)))
```

We can use it to convert infix mathematical expressions to prefix Lisp expressions (see the above linked article for the code):

```
CL-USER 52 > (infix-prefix '(2 * 3 ^ 4))
(* 2 (EXPT 3 4))
```

When we change that assoc list, then the conversion will be different. Let's change the weight of the `^` operator:

```
CL-USER 53 > (defparameter *binary-operators*
               '((+ 1 +)
                 (- 1 -)
                 (* 2 *)
                 (x 2 *)
                 (/ 2 %)
                 (^ 1 expt)))     ; weight changed to 1
*BINARY-OPERATORS*
```

Now we can convert the example from above and we get a different Lisp form:

```
CL-USER 54 > (infix-prefix '(2 * 3 ^ 4))
(EXPT (* 2 3) 4)
```

So, `*binary-operators*` is data, which drives the conversion from infix mathematical expressions to Lisp forms. Instead of hardwiring the rules into the code, here we are using an *assoc list* to keep the mappings. Thus allows us to add new operators by changing the *assoc list*, without changing the actual code.